# MySql select certain columns from a table based on a value from that same table

Tags: mysql

In MySql, how can I select certain columns only depending on the value of a certain column I'm selecting?

```
"id"    "postTitle" "postBody"  "postCategory"  "postStatus"    "userId"    "userName"
"1"     "Title 1"   "Body 1"    "Alcohol"       "0"             "1"         "norman"
"2"     "Title 2"   "Body 2"    "Books"         "1"             "1"         "norman"
```

Eg: From the Table above, I'm trying to select only the `postTitle` if `postStatus = 0`, but `postTitle` & `postBody` & `postCategory` if `postStatus != 0`

It works out to something like this, but this wont work

```
select if postStatus != 0 then
postTitle, postBody, postCategory
else
postTitle
End If
from tablea where id = 2;
```

I tried using case, but it works with one column and not if I select more

```
select case postStatus when 1 then
postTitle, postBody
else
postTitle
End
from tablea where id = 2;
```

Is there a way something like what I'm attempting to do can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using UNION operator,

```
SELECT postTitle ,'' AS postBody ,'' AS  postCategory FROM tableName 
WHERE postStatus = '0'
UNION 
SELECT postTitle ,postBody , postCategory FROM tableName
WHERE postStatus != '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm trying to select only the `postTitle` if `postStatus = 0`, but `postTitle` & `postBody` & `postCategory` if `postStatus != 0`*

You have to use `case` check for every column to be displayed.

**Example**:

```
select 
  , posttitle
  , case when poststatus = 0 then '' else postbody end as postbody
  , case when poststatus = 0 then '' else postCategory end as postCategory
from tableA where id=2;
```